# How to use bitvector32 properly

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have

```
Dim bv As New Specialized.BitVector32(25)
Dim sb As String = "0b" 'I resisted the urge to use a stringbuilder

For i As Integer = 31 To 0 Step -1
    sb &= IIf(bv(i), 1, 0)
Next

Console.WriteLine(sb)
```

And I get

```
0b00000011000000110000001100000011
```

I only wanted to use BitVector32 for bit flags and I wanted the output to be

```
0b00000000000000000000000000011001
```

How do I set this up properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `BitVector32` is a *mask*, not a bit offset. `BitArray` is probably closer to what you want.

(edit) hmmm - maybe the easiest thing is to use shift operators; in C#:

```
    for(int i = 31 ; i >= 0; i--) {
        sb += bv[1 << i] ? "1" : "0";
    }
```

Also note that index 0 refers to the LSB - so you need to reverse the loop.

Or easier:

```
Convert.ToString(25, 2).PadLeft(32, '0');
```

Comment: I changed the line to sb &= IIf(bv(Specialized.BitVector32.CreateMask(i)), 1, 0) and the output is 0b00000000000000000001000100010001. Still not quite right. Also performance wise, I'll only need bitmasks with 32bit integers, would you still recommend bitarray?

Comment: I actually need to play with the bits (there are some bitwise operations before this), I just converted it to a string so I can show my problem easier.

Comment: @Herp - added a *working* example (sorry about that); and re manipulation, I really would just use the inbuilt operators against `int`...

Comment: vb got bitwise functions now. I suppose creating the mask as we go would be ok too. sb &= IIf(bv(1 << i), 1, 0) worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: But if we are going to create the mask ourself that's pretty much makes bitvector32 obsolete doesnt it? Just create the mask and "AND" it with the integer.

Comment: @Herp indeed, that is why I said to just use `int`... Not sure what is up with `CreateMask` - if you can get it to behave, I'd love to know. It isn't being obvious to me...

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                              ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        '
        Dim myBits As New Bits()
        myBits.BitSetVal(25)
        Debug.WriteLine(myBits.toBitString(""))
        myBits.BitClearVal(25)

        For x As Integer = 0 To 31
            myBits.BitSet(x)
            Debug.WriteLine(myBits.BitVal(x).ToString("n0"))
        Next
        Debug.WriteLine(myBits.toBitString("", 4))

        For x As Integer = 31 To 0 Step -1
            myBits.BitClear(x)
            Debug.WriteLine(myBits.toBitString("", 4))
        Next

    End Sub
End Class

Class Bits
    Dim _theBits As Integer
    Const _allOnes As Integer = -1

    Public Sub New()
        Me._theBits = 0
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal initialValue As Integer)
        Me._theBits = initialValue
    End Sub

    Public Sub BitSet(ByVal theBitToSet As Integer) 'set one bit
        If theBitToSet < 0 OrElse theBitToSet > 31 Then throwRangeException("set")
        Dim foo As Integer = 1 << theBitToSet
        Me._theBits = Me._theBits Or foo
    End Sub

    Public Sub BitSetVal(ByVal theValToSet As Integer) 'set a value
        Me._theBits = Me._theBits Or theValToSet
    End Sub

    Public Sub BitSetAll() 'set all bits
        Me._theBits = _allOnes
    End Sub

    Public Sub BitClear(ByVal theBitToClear As Integer) 'clear one bit
        If theBitToClear < 0 OrElse theBitToClear > 31 Then throwRangeException("clear")
        Dim foo As Integer = (1 << theBitToClear) Xor _allOnes
        Me._theBits = Me._theBits And foo
    End Sub

    Public Sub BitClearVal(ByVal theValToClear As Integer) 'clear bit value
        Dim foo As Integer = theValToClear Xor _allOnes
        Me._theBits = Me._theBits And foo
    End Sub

    Public Sub BitClearAll() 'clear all bits
        Me._theBits = 0
    End Sub

    Public Function BitGet(ByVal theBitToGet As Integer) As Boolean 'get bit state
        If theBitToGet < 0 OrElse theBitToGet > 31 Then throwRangeException("get")
        Dim foo As Integer = 1 << theBitToGet
        If (Me._theBits And foo) = foo Then Return True Else Return False
    End Function

    Public Function BitVal(ByVal theBitToGet As Integer) As Integer 'return the value of a bit
        If theBitToGet < 0 OrElse theBitToGet > 31 Then throwRangeException("val")
        Dim foo As Integer = 1 << theBitToGet
        Return Me._theBits And foo
    End Function

    Public Function toBitString(Optional ByVal FormatString As String = "", Optional ByVal Spacing As Integer = 0) As String
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        If FormatString = "" Then
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(Me._theBits, 2).PadLeft(32, "0"c))
        ElseIf FormatString.ToLower = "h" Then
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(Me._theBits, 16).PadLeft(8, "0"c))
        End If

        If Spacing <> 0 Then
            For z As Integer = sb.Length - Spacing To Spacing Step -Spacing
                sb.Insert(z, " ")
            Next
        End If
        Return sb.ToString

    End Function

    Private Sub throwRangeException(ByVal who As String)
        Throw New ArgumentException(String.Format("Bit to {0} must be >= 0 and <= 31", who))
    End Sub
End Class
```